# type of parameter when using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

In a library, there is a function takes a Class object as parameter:

```
public void libMethod(Class<?> cls){...}
```

I need to invoke this library function in Java Reflection way.

For example I have a class :

```
public MySchool extends School{...}
```

I want to pass `MySchool` class to the library function. I tried:

```
//I can successfully get library class & a instance of it
Class<?> libClass = GET_LIB_CLASS();

//How can I define the type for the parameter?
Method m = libClass.getDeclaredMethod("libMethod", new Class[]{MySchool.class});
return m.invoke(libClass.newInstance(), MySchool.class);
```

I tried in above way, but it doesn't work.

How can I define the type for the parameter in my above java reflection way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your method takes argument of type `Class<?>`. The argument you pass to the [`Class#getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) is an array of `Class` instances for the format parameter types of that method, which in this case will be `Class.class`, and not `MySchool.class`.

So, you should get the method as:

```
Method m = libClass.getDeclaredMethod("libMethod", new Class[]{Class.class});
```